# Can I be sure my Java web app running on localhost:8080 is invisible from my fellow Starbucks customers?

Tags: java, security, spring, windows-7

I'm developing a Spring application on my Windows 7 machine and running it on localhost:8080.

Is there any chance that if I do this in a public location like Starbucks that it is possible for my app to be visible to others?

(I'm using Windows Firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials)

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure that it is binding to `localhost:8080` (i.e., `127.0.0.1`), not all interfaces (which is probably the default).  Server programs usually have an option to say which IP addresses to bind.  For example, in Apache, you can provide an IP address to the `Listen` directive in addition to a port number.  If you only bind to `127.0.0.1`, the port will not be open for people scanning your external IP address.

Comment: *If you only bind to 127.0.0.1, the port will not be open for people scanning your external IP address.* ... unless they are using your own browser as a proxy. See my answer below.

Comment: @Zed: Would making sure the app checks the `Host` header fix that?  The Web page couldn't spoof that without also changing the JavaScript origin, right?

Comment: @Jeremiah: You can open raw TCP sockets using Flash or Java applets. Then you can send whatever headers you like. In fact, you don't have to limit yourself to HTTP, you can connect to pretty much any service you like.

Comment: @Zed: Do those have the same-origin policy, and do they compare based on domain names rather than IP addresses?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Only domains. The IP address can be different.

Comment: @Zed: It looks like these problems have all been fixed: http://crypto.stanford.edu/dns/ and http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy claim that, anyway.

Comment: @Jeremiah: What I was saying is that the same origin policy as implemented in most of the browsers in use today if not all of them applies to domain names and not IP addresses. Fixing it would break a lot of things, from load balancers to content delivery networks. Quoting your second link: "Because none of these methods is entirely bullet-proof or problem-free, as of now, a vast majority of browsers implement no default protection against Internet → intranet fenceposts - although such mechanisms are being planned, tested, or offered optionally in response to previously demonstrated attacks."

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer: No.

**Long answer: Someone might access your app like this:**

If you visit a malicious website (if anyone at Starbucks is poisoning the DNS cache or spoofing DNS responses then you may visit a malicious website at www.google.com not knowing about it) then the attacker may send you to his domain with a DNS server (which may in fact be on his laptop) replying to the same query with very short TTL once with his IP, then with 127.0.0.1, then his IP again, etc. That way when you are sent to (http://www.example.com:8080) it is resolved as the attacker's IP and you get the website which starts an AJAX request to the same domain and the same port (so the same origin policy is satisfied in every browser) but thanks to the short TTL you don't have the domain entry in your cache any more, so you ask again and this time you get the answer 127.0.0.1 which incidentally is your own loopback interface which you assume to be invisible from the outside - and it is in fact invisible from the outside but perfectly visible from your browser. Your browser will happily connect to your app at 127.0.0.1:8080 and proxy the request to the attacker with another AJAX connection or any other side channel. Voilà, your app is now connected to the world!

Things like this happen in the wild so be careful. Sometimes people even access admin interfaces in routers behind NAT and firewalls that way. Quite frankly I'm pretty scared by all of the responses telling you that it is impossible to access anything running on localhost. Be careful what you do.

Comment: that's pretty scary. I can't say that I can follow the flow in detail but it sounds plausible.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any chance that if I do this in a public location like Starbucks that it is possible for my app to be visible to others?

Of course! People can look over your shoulder.

Answer (score 2):

what Jeremiah said. use `netstat -an` to check what addresses it bound to.

and never trust Windows firewall, or any other software to which you don't have the source.

Comment: of course, I'm assuming nobody can actually login to your computer, in which case all bets are off :^)

Answer (score 1):

If the port is open it can be.  If you program it to only accept connections from localhost while developing then even if they can see it, they wont be able to connect to it.

Comment: but a port is bound to an interface, correct? and localhost, even on Windows, is a separate interface from that of any actual NICs. so the port being open on one interface should not make it open on another; which would make it invisible to the other coffee slurpers.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx : By default a listening port is bound to *all* interfaces. You need to do something specific, i.e. use new ServerSocket(port, backlog, ip) with a non-null IP address, to prevent that.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: The socket may not listen on other interfaces but your web browser can be used as a proxy using AJAX and a simple DNS trick. See my answer above.